# When I attach a Light to a Node do I have to move the position of the Light? It's because I can't see the light at all

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, sceneview

I've been struggling with this for the past month and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. All I'm do is trying to add a Light to a Node, to make it overall brighter. Do I have to move the attached Light? Someone please help me.

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(
                        this,
                        Uri.parse("squarecard.sfb")
                )
                .build()
                .thenAccept(
                        modelRenderable -> {

                            Light spotLightYellow =
                                    Light.builder(Light.Type.FOCUSED_SPOTLIGHT)
                                            .setColor(new Color(android.graphics.Color.YELLOW))
                                            .setShadowCastingEnabled(true)
                                            .build();
  
                            node.setParent(scene);
                            node.setLocalPosition(positionOfNode);
                            node.setLocalScale(new Vector3(1.4f, 1.4f, 1.4f));



                            node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);

                            node.setLight(spotLightYellow);
                        })
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Toast toast =
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load Fox renderable" + throwable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                      });
```

I don't see any difference when I attach the light, to my rendered model node. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.